# Spark iteration time increasing exponentially when using join

Tags: python, loops, apache-spark, iteration, pyspark

I'm quite new to Spark and I'm trying to implement some iterative algorithm for clustering (expectation-maximization) with centroid represented by Markov model. So I need to do iterations and joins.

One problem that I experience is that each iterations time growth exponentially.
After some experimenting I found that when doing iterations it's needed to persist RDD that is going to be reused in the next iteration, otherwise every iteration spark will create execution plan that will recalculate the RDD from from start, thus increasing calculation time.

```
init = sc.parallelize(xrange(10000000), 3)
init.cache()

for i in range(6):
    print i
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    init2 = init.map(lambda n: (n, n*3))        
    init = init2.map(lambda n: n[0])
#     init.cache()

    print init.count()    
    print str(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Results in:

```
0
10000000
0:00:04.283652
1
10000000
0:00:05.998830
2
10000000
0:00:08.771984
3
10000000
0:00:11.399581
4
10000000
0:00:14.206069
5
10000000
0:00:16.856993
```

So adding cache() helps and iteration time become constant.

```
init = sc.parallelize(xrange(10000000), 3)
init.cache()

for i in range(6):
    print i
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    init2 = init.map(lambda n: (n, n*3))        
    init = init2.map(lambda n: n[0])
    init.cache()

    print init.count()    
    print str(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
0
10000000
0:00:04.966835
1
10000000
0:00:04.609885
2
10000000
0:00:04.324358
3
10000000
0:00:04.248709
4
10000000
0:00:04.218724
5
10000000
0:00:04.223368
```

But when making Join inside the iteration the problem comes back.
Here is some simple code I demonstrating the problem. Even making cache on each RDD transformation doesn't solve the problem:

```
init = sc.parallelize(xrange(10000), 3)
init.cache()

for i in range(6):
    print i
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    init2 = init.map(lambda n: (n, n*3))
    init2.cache()

    init3 = init.map(lambda n: (n, n*2))
    init3.cache()

    init4 = init2.join(init3)
    init4.count()
    init4.cache()

    init = init4.map(lambda n: n[0])
    init.cache()

    print init.count()    
    print str(datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

And here is the output. As you can see iteration time growing exponentially :(

```
0
10000
0:00:00.674115
1
10000
0:00:00.833377
2
10000
0:00:01.525314
3
10000
0:00:04.194715
4
10000
0:00:08.139040
5
10000
0:00:17.852815
```

I will really appreciate any help :)

Comment: Ok, I found that calling <action> inside the interaction creates the problem of lineage growth. So if number of iterations is constant you don't need to cache the rdd between iterations, which is not the case with clustering, since I want to stop iterating depending on convergence.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Summary**:

Generally speaking iterative algorithms, especially ones with self-join or self-union, require a control over:

- Length of the lineage (see for example [Stackoverflow due to long RDD Lineage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34461804/1560062) and [unionAll resulting in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187333/1560062)).
- Number of partitions.

Problem described here is a result of the lack of the former one. In each iteration number of partition increases with self-join leading to exponential pattern. To address that you have to either control number of partitions in each iteration (see below) or use global tools like `spark.default.parallelism` (see [an answer provided by Travis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32769637/1560062)). In general the first approach provides much more control in general and doesn't affect other parts of code.

**Original answer**:

As far as I can tell there are two interleaved problems here - growing number of partitions and shuffling overhead during joins. Both can be easily handled so lets go step by step.

First lets create a helper to collect the statistics:

```
import datetime

def get_stats(i, init, init2, init3, init4,
       start, end, desc, cache, part, hashp):
    return {
        "i": i,
        "init": init.getNumPartitions(),
        "init1": init2.getNumPartitions(),
        "init2": init3.getNumPartitions(),
        "init4": init4.getNumPartitions(),
        "time": str(end - start),
        "timen": (end - start).seconds + (end - start).microseconds * 10 **-6,
        "desc": desc,
        "cache": cache,
        "part": part,
        "hashp": hashp
    }
```

another helper to handle caching/partitioning

```
def procRDD(rdd, cache=True, part=False, hashp=False, npart=16):
    rdd = rdd if not part else rdd.repartition(npart)
    rdd = rdd if not hashp else rdd.partitionBy(npart)
    return rdd if not cache else rdd.cache()
```

extract pipeline logic:

```
def run(init, description, cache=True, part=False, hashp=False, 
    npart=16, n=6):
    times = []

    for i in range(n):
        start = datetime.datetime.now()

        init2 = procRDD(
                init.map(lambda n: (n, n*3)),
                cache, part, hashp, npart)
        init3 = procRDD(
                init.map(lambda n: (n, n*2)),
                cache, part, hashp, npart)


        # If part set to True limit number of the output partitions
        init4 = init2.join(init3, npart) if part else init2.join(init3) 
        init = init4.map(lambda n: n[0])

        if cache:
            init4.cache()
            init.cache()

        init.count() # Force computations to get time
        end = datetime.datetime.now() 

        times.append(get_stats(
            i, init, init2, init3, init4,
            start, end, description,
            cache, part, hashp
        ))

    return times
```

and create initial data:

```
ncores = 8
init = sc.parallelize(xrange(10000), ncores * 2).cache()
```

Join operation by itself, if `numPartitions` argument is not provided, adjust number of partitions in the output based on the number of partitions of the input RDDs. It means growing number of partitions with each iteration. If number of partitions is to large things get ugly. You can deal with these by providing `numPartitions` argument for join or repartition RDDs with each iteration.

```
timesCachePart = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
        run(init, "cache + partition", True, True, False, ncores * 2))
timesCachePart.select("i", "init1", "init2", "init4", "time", "desc").show()

+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------------+
|i|init1|init2|init4|          time|             desc|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------------+
|0|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.145625|cache + partition|
|1|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.090468|cache + partition|
|2|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.059316|cache + partition|
|3|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.029544|cache + partition|
|4|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.033493|cache + partition|
|5|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.007598|cache + partition|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+-----------------+
```

As you can see when we repartition execution time is more or less constant.
The second problem is that above data is partitioned randomly. To ensure join performance we would like to have same keys on a single partition. To achieve that we can use hash partitioner:

```
timesCacheHashPart = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    run(init, "cache + hashpart", True, True, True, ncores * 2))
timesCacheHashPart.select("i", "init1", "init2", "init4", "time", "desc").show()

+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+----------------+
|i|init1|init2|init4|          time|            desc|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+----------------+
|0|   16|   16|   16|0:00:00.946379|cache + hashpart|
|1|   16|   16|   16|0:00:00.966519|cache + hashpart|
|2|   16|   16|   16|0:00:00.945501|cache + hashpart|
|3|   16|   16|   16|0:00:00.986777|cache + hashpart|
|4|   16|   16|   16|0:00:00.960989|cache + hashpart|
|5|   16|   16|   16|0:00:01.026648|cache + hashpart|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+----------------+
```

Execution time is constant as before and There is a small improvement over the basic partitioning.

Now lets use cache only as a reference:

```
timesCacheOnly = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    run(init, "cache-only", True, False, False, ncores * 2))
timesCacheOnly.select("i", "init1", "init2", "init4", "time", "desc").show()


+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+----------+
|i|init1|init2|init4|          time|      desc|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+----------+
|0|   16|   16|   32|0:00:00.992865|cache-only|
|1|   32|   32|   64|0:00:01.766940|cache-only|
|2|   64|   64|  128|0:00:03.675924|cache-only|
|3|  128|  128|  256|0:00:06.477492|cache-only|
|4|  256|  256|  512|0:00:11.929242|cache-only|
|5|  512|  512| 1024|0:00:23.284508|cache-only|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+----------+
```

As you can see number of partitions (init2, init3, init4) for cache-only version doubles with each iteration and execution time is proportional to the number of partitions.

Finally we can check if we can improve performance with large number of partitions if we use hash partitioner:

```
timesCacheHashPart512 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    run(init, "cache + hashpart 512", True, True, True, 512))
timesCacheHashPart512.select(
    "i", "init1", "init2", "init4", "time", "desc").show()
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+--------------------+
|i|init1|init2|init4|          time|                desc|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+--------------------+
|0|  512|  512|  512|0:00:14.492690|cache + hashpart 512|
|1|  512|  512|  512|0:00:20.215408|cache + hashpart 512|
|2|  512|  512|  512|0:00:20.408070|cache + hashpart 512|
|3|  512|  512|  512|0:00:20.390267|cache + hashpart 512|
|4|  512|  512|  512|0:00:20.362354|cache + hashpart 512|
|5|  512|  512|  512|0:00:19.878525|cache + hashpart 512|
+-+-----+-----+-----+--------------+--------------------+
```

Improvement is not so impressive but if you have a small cluster and a lot of data it is still worth trying.

I guess take away message here is partitioning matters. There are contexts where it is handled for you (`mllib`, `sql`) but if you use low level operations it is your responsibility.

Comment: zero323 it solved my problem like a charm and improved my understanding of spark - thanks a lot!!!

Comment: One additional question - why you doubling partitions number from 

`init = sc.parallelize(xrange(10000), ncores)`

to

`init2 = init.map(lambda n: (n, n*3)).partitionBy(ncores * 2).cache()
init3 = init.map(lambda n: (n, n*2)).partitionBy(ncores * 2).cache()
init4 = init2.join(init3, ncores * 2).cache()`

Comment: No particular reason. It was just a default value on my local machine. As a rule of thumb you should use twice as much partitions as a number of available cores, but it depends on other factors like amount of data, IO throughput and so on.

Comment: @zero323, I have met a simlilar problem with graph object in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962464/spark-graphx-time-cost-increases-stably-per-round-in-linearly-style), the solution of rdd seems not work on graph vertices rdd.

Comment: I was facing this same problem when doing a flatMap that produced two items for every entry in an RDD. This doubled the number of partitions. In my case, this was immediately followed by a union with another RDD and a groupByKey. I solved the problem by setting the number of partitions in the groupByKey to the original number of partitions before the flatMap: `groupByKey(orig_num_partitions)`.

Comment: Nice answer! But what happens for Dataframes instead of RDDs and iterativeUnions instead of Joins?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is (as zero323 pointed out in his thorough answer) that calling join without specifying the number of partitions may (does) result in a growing number of partitions.  The number of partitions can grow (apparently) without bound.  There are (at least) two ways to prevent the number of partitions from growing (without bound) when repeatedly calling join.

**Method 1:**

As zero323 pointed out, you can specify the number of partitions manually when you call join.  For example

```
rdd1.join(rdd2, numPartitions)
```

This will ensure that the number of Partitions does not exceed numPartitions and in particular the number of partitions will not continually grow.

**Method 2:**

When you create your SparkConf you can specify the default level of parallelism.  If this value is set, then when you call functions like `join` without specifying numPartitions, the default parallelism will be used instead, effectively capping the number of partitions and preventing them from growing.  You can set this parameter as

```
conf=SparkConf.set("spark.default.parallelism", numPartitions)
sc = SparkContex(conf=conf)
```

Answer (score -2):

Rdds are immutable. Try to do `rdd = rdd.cache()`

Comment: It is not a problem here: `rdd = sc.parallelize([]); rdd.is_cached; rdd.cache(); rdd.is_cached`. `cache()` actually modifies `is_cached` field.