# Spark Graphx: Time Cost increases stably per round in linearly style

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I use graphx api in a iterative alogrithm. Although [I have carefully cache/ unpersist rdd, and take care of the vertices partition num](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659404/spark-iteration-time-increasing-exponentially-when-using-join/31662127#31662127). The time cost still seems increases per round in a lineary trend. The simplified version of my code as following, and it gets the same problem:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer


object ComputingTimeProblem extends App {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    var graph = GraphGenerators
        .logNormalGraph(sc, 15000).mapVertices((_, _) => 1d)
        .cache
    graph.vertices.take(10).foreach(println)

    val maxIter = 50

    var preGraph: Graph[Double, Int] = null
    var allTime: ArrayBuffer[Double] = ArrayBuffer()
    for (i <- 1 to maxIter) {

        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()

        preGraph = graph

        val vertices2 = graph.triplets.map(tri => (tri.srcId, tri.dstAttr)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
        graph = graph.joinVertices(vertices2)((vid, left, right) => left + right).cache
        graph.vertices.take(10)

        preGraph.unpersist()

        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val duration = (end - begin) / (60 * 1000d)
        allTime += duration
        println(s"Round ${i} Time Cost: %.4f min, Vertices Partition Num: %d".format(
            duration, graph.vertices.getNumPartitions))
    }

    graph.vertices.take(10).foreach(println)

    val avgTime = allTime.sum / allTime.size
    println(s"Average Time = ${avgTime}")

    val timeCostDiffs = for (i <- 1 until maxIter) yield (allTime(i) - allTime(i - 1))
    timeCostDiffs
        .zipWithIndex
        .map(x => "Round %d to %d, Time Cost Diff: %.4f min".format(x._2+1, x._2 + 2, x._1))
        .foreach(println)

    println("tc\n"+allTime.mkString("\n"))
}
```

Time cost trend as following
[image]

I have not changed the index of the graph object, and the graphx would join the vertices by [leftZipJoin](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/impl/VertexRDDImpl.scala#L150) method, which not requiring shuffling, so why the time cost still increase per round. 
Can anybody give some constructive options, thanks?!

Answer (score 1):

It still an lineage problem, I have just found. Graph object has two rdd: vertex rdd and edge rdd. In the above code, I have just materialized vertex rdd, not edge rdd. So, each round, it will recompute the previous edges agagin. So, materializing both rdd with **triplets** object will solve the problem, as following:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer


object ComputingTimeProblem extends App {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    var graph = GraphGenerators
        .logNormalGraph(sc, 15000).mapVertices((_, _) => 1d)
        //        .partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut,8)
        .cache
    graph.vertices.take(10).foreach(println)

    val maxIter = 50

    var preGraph: Graph[Double, Int] = null
    var allTime: ArrayBuffer[Double] = ArrayBuffer()
    for (i <- 1 to maxIter) {
        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()

        preGraph = graph

        val vertices2 = graph.triplets.map(tri => (tri.srcId, tri.dstAttr)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
        graph = graph.joinVertices(vertices2)((vid, left, right) => left + right).cache
        graph.triplets.take(10) // here materialize both vertex and edge rdd
        // graph.vertices.take(10)

        preGraph.unpersist()

        val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val duration = (end - begin) / (60 * 1000d)
        allTime += duration
        println(s"Round ${i} Time Cost: %.4f min, Vertices Partition Num: %d".format(
            duration, graph.vertices.getNumPartitions))
    }

    graph.vertices.take(10).foreach(println)

    val avgTime = allTime.sum / allTime.size
    println(s"Average Time = ${avgTime}")

    val timeCostDiffs = for (i <- 1 until maxIter) yield (allTime(i) - allTime(i - 1))
    timeCostDiffs
        .zipWithIndex
        .map(x => "Round %d to %d, Time Cost Diff: %.4f min".format(x._2 + 1, x._2 + 2, x._1))
        .foreach(println)


    println("tc\n" + allTime.mkString("\n"))

}
```