# Spark: Running Backwards Elimination By P-Value With Linear Regressions

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I presently have a Spark Dataframe with 2 columns:
1) a column where each row contains a vector of predictive features
2) a column containing the value to be predicted.

To discern the most predictive features for use in a later model, I am using backwards elimination by P-value, as outlined by [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/backward-elimination-for-feature-selection-in-machine-learning-c6a3a8f8cef4). Below is my code:

```
num_vars = scoresDf.select("filtered_features").take(1)[0][0].__len__()
for i in range(0, num_vars):
    model = LinearRegression(featuresCol="filtered_features", labelCol="averageScore")
    model = model.fit(scoresDf)
    p_values = model.summary.pValues
    max_p = np.max(p_values)
    if max_p > 0.05:
        max_index = p_values.index(max_p)
        drop_max_index_udf = udf(lambda elem, drop_index, var_count:
                                 Vectors.dense([elem[j] for j in range(var_count) if j not in [drop_index]]), VectorUDT())
        scoresDfs = scoresDf.withColumn("filtered_features", drop_max_index_udf(scoresDf["filtered_features"],
                                                                               lit(max_index), lit(num_vars)))
        num_vars = scoresDf.select("filtered_features").take(1)[0][0].__len__()
```

The code runs, but the only problem is that every iteration takes drastically longer than the last. Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39084739/evaluating-spark-dataframe-in-loop-slows-down-with-every-iteration-all-work-don), it appears that the code is re-evaluating all prior iterations every time.

Ideally, I would like to feed the entire logic into some Pipeline structure that would store it all lazily and then execute sequentially with no repeats when called upon, but I am unsure as to whether that is even possible given that none of Spark's estimator / transformer functions seem to fit this use case.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the model repeatedly inside a loop. It is a time consuming process and needs to be done once per training data set and a set of parameters. Try the following -

```
num_vars = scoresDf.select("filtered_features").take(1)[0][0].__len__()
modelAlgo = LinearRegression(featuresCol="filtered_features", labelCol="averageScore")
model = modelAlgo.fit(scoresDf)

for i in range(0, num_vars):

    p_values = model.summary.pValues
    max_p = np.max(p_values)
    if max_p > 0.05:
        max_index = p_values.index(max_p)
        drop_max_index_udf = udf(lambda elem, drop_index, var_count:
                                 Vectors.dense([elem[j] for j in range(var_count) if j not in [drop_index]]), VectorUDT())
        scoresDfs = scoresDf.withColumn("filtered_features", drop_max_index_udf(scoresDf["filtered_features"],
                                                                               lit(max_index), lit(num_vars)))
        num_vars = scoresDf.select("filtered_features").take(1)[0][0].__len__()
```

Once you are happy with the model you save it. When you need to evaluate your data just read this model and predict with it.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Salim! The only caveat is that I have to re-fit the model every time the "filtered_features" column is updated, and then use the new p values in the for loop. The above solution re-uses the p-values from the first fitting for the entire loop. Is there a way to efficiently re-fit the model in every iteration?

Comment: It will take time for iteratively training the model.

Comment: But is there a way for the logic to not have to re-compute every prior iteration of scoresDf and the regression in every new iteration? Because that seems to be the reason every iteration is longer than the prior.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing

```
model = model.fit(scoresDf)
```

when `scoredDfs` contains your new df with one less independent variable?

---

If you change your code with the following:

```
independent_vars = ['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']

def remove_element(array, index):
    return Vectors.dense(np.delete(array, index, 0))

remove_element_udf = udf(lambda a, i: remove_element(a, i), VectorUDT())

max_p = 1
i = 0
while (max_p > 0.05):
    model = LinearRegression(featuresCol="filtered_features", 
                             labelCol="averageScore",
                             fitIntercept=False)
    model = model.fit(scoresDf)

    print('iteration: ', i)
    summary = model.summary
    summary_df = pd.DataFrame({
        'var': independent_vars,
        'coeff': model.coefficients,
        'se': summary.coefficientStandardErrors,
        'p_value': summary.pValues
    })
    print(summary_df)
    print("r2: %f" % summary.r2)    

    p_values = summary.pValues
    max_p = np.max(p_values)
    if max_p > 0.05:
        max_index = p_values.index(max_p)
        max_var = independent_vars[max_index]
        print('-> max_index {max_index}, corresponding to var {var}'.format(max_index=max_index, var=max_var))
        scoresDf = scoresDf.withColumn("filtered_features", remove_element_udf(scoresDf["filtered_features"],
                                                                               lit(max_index)))
        independent_vars = np.delete(independent_vars, max_index, 0)

    print()
    i += 1
```

you will get

```
iteration:  0
  var     coeff        se   p_value
0  x0  0.174697  0.207794  0.402616
1  x1 -0.448982  0.203421  0.029712
2  x2 -0.452940  0.233972  0.055856
3  x3 -3.213578  0.209935  0.000000
4  x4  3.790730  0.212917  0.000000
r2: 0.870330
-> max_index 0, corresponding to var x0

iteration:  1
  var     coeff        se   p_value
0  x1 -0.431835  0.202087  0.035150
1  x2 -0.460711  0.233432  0.051297
2  x3 -3.218725  0.209525  0.000000
3  x4  3.768661  0.210970  0.000000
r2: 0.869365
-> max_index 1, corresponding to var x2

iteration:  2
  var     coeff        se   p_value
0  x1 -0.479803  0.203592  0.020449
1  x3 -3.344830  0.202501  0.000000
2  x4  3.669419  0.207925  0.000000
r2: 0.864065
```

in first and second iteration, two independent variables with p-value greater than 0.05 are removed

Comment: Thanks for the response! The method only removes the index with the highest p-value in each iteration, regardless of how many of them are > 0.05

Comment: The variable with highest p-value is going to be the same at each iteration, given that the fitted df is not changing. I believe your code is not doing what it was meant for (backward elimination article)